# How to use promise for async function?

Tags: javascript, promise, puppeteer

How can I use promise for this async function?

When I call async function, sometimes it fails and in the log it says unhandled promise. How can I use promise here?

```
async function getDate(param) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    const targetUrl = `http://some-site.com/summary?t= ${param} &culture=en_US`;
    await page.goto(targetUrl);

    const dateSelector = "some-css-selector";

    const dateText = await page.evaluate((sel) => {
        return document.querySelectorAll(sel)[0].innerHTML;
    }, dateSelector);

    const date = dateText.substring(6, 16);
    console.log(date);

    browser.close();
    return date;
}
//I am calling this function this way
const myDate = getDate(myParam);
```

Edit 1:
As suggested, I added try/catch block which seem to solve the issue of error.

Now, how do I use `.then()` on `myDate`?
Since `getDate()` is async function, it is a promise. I would like to do something like this when promise is resolved:

```
myDate.then(
        console.log(`date1`, myDate)
    )
```

Right now it is coming as

```
date1 Promise { <pending> }
```

Edit 2:
This solved it

```
myDate.then(result => console.log(result))
```

Comment: the error is because you have some not caught error in your async code. Wrap the await operations with a try catch and in the catch you should be able to catch the errors

Comment: You have to wrap it in a `try/catch` block.

Comment: try this. const myDate = await getDate(myParam)

Comment: _How can I use promise for this async function_ <-- what do you really mean? The result returned by an `async function` is always a `Promise`, so you can just use the result if it's what you meant.

Comment: You didn't exactly return anything from your async function. Not quite sure what you expected that to do.

Comment: @KevinB, my bad. I want to return date from async function. Edited question with it.

Comment: @elefher, I am getting `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`  when I try `const myDate = await getDate(myParam)`

Comment: you need to put your code into an anonymous async function. You can do this. (async () => {
    const myDate = await getDate(myParam);
})();

Comment: I just saw your fixed above. That's one way to run the async function and it's correct. The second is that I wrote in my previous answer

Answer (score 0):

Use `try/catch`.

```
async function getDate(param) {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    const targetUrl = `http://some-site.com/summary?t= ${param} &culture=en_US`;
    await page.goto(targetUrl);

    const dateSelector = "some-css-selector";

    const dateText = await page.evaluate((sel) => {
        return document.querySelectorAll(sel)[0].innerHTML;
    }, dateSelector);

    const date = dateText.substring(6, 16);
    console.log(date);

    browser.close();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

Read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)